# Issues with Stageros

Tags: ros, simulation, stage, stageros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to work with stage (again). Brings back memories... Anyway, I don't know why it's not working. Maybe the syntax has changed a little... Either way, this is what I get when I tried [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/IntroductiontoStageControllers):

```
allenh1@muri-pc7:~$ rosrun stage stageros `rospack find stage_controllers`/world/roomba-wander.world
 [Loading /home/allenh1/ros/stage_controllers/world/roomba-wander.world][Image "bitmaps/roomba-stage.png"]
err: Model type laser not found in model typetable (/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/world.cc CreateModel)
err: Unknown model type laser in world file. (/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/world.cc CreateModel)
```

I'm just copy/pasting the command from the tutorial, so I assume it should work...

Thanks in advance,

-Hunter A.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38944/issues-with-stageros/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
check this [answer/question](http://answers.ros.org/question/33973/stage-error-in-fuerte/).
regards

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1